# How to select the next value if the first value is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to write those Select subquery so that if the Top 1 value is NULL, it would move to the next value that is not NULL. Here is the code:

```
----------------- GATHERING DATE DATA FROM ALL 12 MONTH UDF'S INTO TEMP TABLE #tmpAll12MonthForms -----------------
select e.RECORD_ID,e.FORM_INSTANCE_ID,e.FORM_NAME,e.[FIELD_VALUE] as [DATE_FORM_COMPLETED],
    row_number() over (partition by record_id order by cast([FIELD_VALUE] as date) desc) as RowNum into #tmpAll12MonthForms
    from [View_CMMode_UDFData] e
    where e.FORM_DEF_DR IN 
    ('HMFPAT12mPostEn','HMFPAT24mPostEn','HMFPAT36mPostEn'
    ,'HMFPAT48mPostEn','HMFPAT60mPostEn'
    ,'HMFPAT72mPostEn','HMFPATEnroll','PATEnroll'
    ,'HMFPATEnrollV01','SCMTmechvEnroll','HMFSCEnroll','HMFNFP12mPostEn'
    ,'HMFNFP24mPostEn','HMFNFPEnroll')
    AND e.FIELD_DEF_DR in ('PATMIECHV12mPostEn','PATMIECHV24mPostEn'
    ,'PATMIECHV12mPostEnGuideDtVstFrmComp'
    ,'PATMIECHV24mPostEnGuideDtVstFrmComp'
    ,'PATMIECHV36mPostEnGuideDtVstFrmComp'
    ,'MTmechv48mPostEnGuideDt','MTmechv60mPostEnGuideDt'
    ,'MTmechv72mPostEnGuideDt' ,'PATEnrollGuideDt','EnrollGuideDt'
    ,'FSMTmechv12mPostEn','FSMTmechv12mPostEnGuideDt'
    ,'NFPMIECHV12mUpdtGuideDt','NFPMIECHV18mUpdtGuideDt'
    ,'NFPMIECHV24mUpdtGuideDt','NFPMIECHV6mUpdtGuideDt'
    ,'NFPMIECHVEnrollGuideDt')
    group by e.record_id,e.FORM_INSTANCE_ID,FORM_NAME,[FIELD_VALUE]

create unique clustered index All12MonthFormsU on #tmpAll12MonthForms (record_id,form_instance_id)

----------------- GATHERING PRENATAL ENROLLIES DATA FROM UDF INTO TEMP TABLE #tmpPrenatal -----------------
SELECT [RECORD_ID],[FORM_INSTANCE_ID],[field_value] as 'Prenatal status' INTO #tmpPrenatal
    FROM [View_CMMode_UDFData]
    where [SECTION_DEF_DR] in ('MTmechvEnrollInfo','FP') and [FIELD_DEF_DR] in ('MTmechvEnrollInfoChldPNEnroll','FPPG')
    GROUP BY [RECORD_ID],[FORM_INSTANCE_ID],[field_value]

------------- COLLECTING CLIENT PRENATAL ENROLLMENT DATA FOR PAT --------------------
SELECT U.RECORD_ID,u.FORM_INSTANCE_ID,u.[Prenatal status],p.RowNum into #TmpPrenatalEnrollPAT
    FROM #tmpPrenatal u inner join #tmpAll12MonthForms p 
    on p.RECORD_ID = u.RECORD_ID and p.FORM_INSTANCE_ID = u.FORM_INSTANCE_ID 
    group by U.RECORD_ID,u.FORM_INSTANCE_ID,u.[Prenatal status],p.RowNum

----------- THIS IS THE SELECT SUBQUERY I AM WORKING ON. THERE ARE MANY LIKE THIS ONE -------------
,(SELECT TOP 1 [Prenatal status]
FROM #TmpPrenatalEnrollPAT as prenatalEnroll WHERE prenatalEnroll.RECORD_ID = ClientSVC.SVC_ID
ORDER BY prenatalEnroll.RowNum asc
) AS PrenatalEnroll
 ............
 ............

 INTO #TempPrimaryCGPAT
 FROM #tmpClientServices AS ClientSVC 
 INNER JOIN #tmpClients AS Client ON Client.PER_ROWID = ClientSVC.SVC_PersonDR

 SELECT .....................
      ,ClientSVC.PER_PRIMARYLANGUAGE as Client_PrimaryLanguage
      ,PrenatalEnroll as [Prenatally Enroll]
      ,ClientSVC.EnrollDate
      ,.............
  into #TMPpatTable
  FROM #TempPrimaryCGPAT AS ClientSVC
  INNER JOIN E_Entity e (nolock) ON e.ID = ClientSVC.PrimaryCGID
  INNER JOIN #tmpClients AS CAREGIVER ON CAREGIVER.PER_ROWID = e.EntityHx_ID
  INNER JOIN #tmpLastHomeVisitPAT V ON V.RECORD_ID = ClientSVC.SVC_ID
```

I would need the code to move on to the next value from the Top 1. RowNum in the Order clause is a row number that was created using a partition in a previous table and as things stand it is equal to 1. This is one of many Select subqueries using this Select Top 1 method. I am using this method to get the most recent information from the query, but if needed, we could fall back on the next most recent data.

Here is some sample output. The entire output is very large with many columns.

```
  Caregiver_MaritalStatus
          Married
  Not Married but Living Together with Partner
           NULL
  Not Married but Living Together with Partner
  Never Married (not including not married but living with partner)
  Not Married but Living Together with Partner
           NULL
         Married
  Not Married but Living Together with Partner
  Not Married but Living Together with Partner
  Not Married but Living Together with Partner
```

Comment: As simple as a where clause? Where [Prenatal status] IS NOT NULL But perhaps sharing the whole query would be a better idea. This looks like a subquery as a column which is very rarely a good approach.

Comment: @Sean Lange I tried that but it seemed to create more Null data in the output. Im just wondering if im missing another way that could be better.

Comment: Well from barely a snippet it is nearly impossible to say. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: At the very least it didnt fix the problem as I would have liked.

Comment: Ok ill show the code for the temp table that it is pulling from.

Comment: The sample data is not going to work for anybody else. We don't have your tables or views. And I can't figure out what the last subquery is part of.

Comment: I understand that problem. Ok well thank you for you input anyway. This query is very long and showing all that is needed may become very cumbersome.

Comment: You don't have to share everything. But you do need to share enough so others can understand the issue.

Comment: Ok I added some more code. Thats about all I can share at this point.

Comment: Can you show us the entire output and what is wrong with it?  In short, I think you'll have to figure out the `where` clause in your `top 1` selects such that you return the result you want while avoiding the `null` value you don't want.

Comment: Another idea -- instead of what appears to be selecting top 1 as a column in a select statement, perhaps you could use it as a joined subquery.  That would allow you to select top 2 or top 3 and then get a `where` clause later to choose the first, second, etc. row that you actually want.

Comment: @avery: Ok thats worth a shot. What would I be joining with in the subquery?

Comment: This honestly looks like it needs a complete rethinking of how you approach this. Whenever I start seeing query after query generating temp tables it is an indication that things are not going to be easy to work with. And from everything you have posted and stated it seems the only fix that makes sense is to add a where clause in your subquery. That is how you would not get a row with NULL.

Comment: you seem to be saying that using '(SELECT TOP 1 [Prenatal status] .... WHERE [Prenatal status] is not NULL ..' failed.   Could it be that there is no non null value available?  you could test by changing to (SELECT COUNT([Prenatal status] ) ..

Comment: OK thats fine. Thats really the only tractable solution at this point. So to be sure, would adding: AND [Prenatal status] IS NOT NULL to the where clause keep a NULL out of the Select Top 1?

Comment: That's what the very first comment meant for you to do.

Comment: @avery Yes this is true!

Comment: if it's a sub-query, then it could be capable of selecting NULL as the TOP 1, unless you tell it not to select NULL.   HOWEVER, it could also select 0 rows, and then possibly show as NULL in the outer query that the sub-query is part of.

Comment: @Cato thats a very good point.

Answer (score 1):

To explain what I think this could be, take this simple query

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT TOP 1 t.name from sys.tables T 
                WHERE 1 = 0 
                AND t.name IS NOT NULL 
                order by T.name
    ) DQ
```

t.name is probably never NULL, and I would never select it, but I never select a row in any case, so you do see NULL - the subquery returns nothing, NULL

this second query shows that there are 0 rows, not that NULL field is being obtained by the query

```
    SELECT 
    (SELECT  COUNT(t.name) from sys.tables T 
                WHERE 1 = 0 
                AND t.name IS NOT NULL 

    ) DQ
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inner join (SELECT [Prenatal status], RECORD_ID, RowNum
            FROM #TmpPrenatalEnrollPAT
            WHERE RowNum < 4
           ) PreNatalEnroll on PreNatalEnroll.RECORD_ID = ClientSVC.SVC_ID
```

Comment: Hmm very interesting. So this would go into the From clause of the temp table that has all those select subqueries?

Comment: Yes.  I just modified it to include RowNum, since that might be useful in the final overall `where` clause.

Comment: If it's possible for #TmpPrenatalEnrollPAT to be empty (or all RowNum >=4), then this should be made a left join.

Comment: While this is a great idea, it would take a long while to implement at this point as it would require an overhaul of the code. The best I can offer you is to keep this in mind when I get the time to do so.

Comment: You could maybe even just join #TmpPrenatlEnrollPAT directly instead of using the subquery and then put everything into your `where` clause.

Comment: OK I think I could give that a shot. This will take a little while....